# Seasons of judgment

Tags: yom-kippur, shoftim--book-of

Seasons of Jugdment

Are there seasons of judgment?Seasons where Hashem judge the world.We know about  Yom Kippur and the seal .But when or in what  season does this judgment take place.Is there a rule?

In any court system or law system there are rules for jugdment and time and  so on.

Comment: Why vote to close and not downvote! What is wrong with the question?

Comment: I personally didn't vote to close, but your question is unclear: if you know about the seal of judgement on Yom Kippur, then how can you immediately ask 'when does this judgement take place'? And what do you mean by 'season'? Do you mean as in autumn, winter etc.? Yom Kippur is generally in the end of summer or autumn. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Jay Well I guess more like When will God revenge , destroy or heal and give peace,restore  something,is there a time for such things?So it is sealed on yom kippur but when will it happen?

Comment: @Jay if you understand my question feel free to edit it

Comment: I think it's self evident that each one of those things can occur at any time of the year. I'm still not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Just wondering if you can understand the time,like if something good is happning iẗ́s because of something that did happen in the year before,like if you can set a date and time for every event.

Answer (score 1):

The second Mishnah in Rosh Hashanah says that Hashem judges different aspects of the world at four different periods: people in Tishrei, grain on Pesach, fruit on Shavuos, and water on Sukkos.

If you're asking specifically about people, the same Mishnah describes how Tzaddikim are immediately sealed for life and Reshaim for death, while the rest of us get ten days to repent and get into the Book of Life. This judgement, though sealed, may still be revoked anytime before it's "delivered," whatever that means, on Hoshanah Rabbah (Zohar Vayechi 120a).

Even so, our actions during the year can affect how the judgement is carried out. If a low level of rainfall was decreed and we repent, the rain might be reserved for opportune locations, such as cisterns and wells (Taanis 8b).

Comment: Interesting ,people in Tishrei, grain on Pesach, fruit on Shavuos, and water on Sukkos.How does that work? Any rabbis written a book about it?

Comment: The Gemara (RH 16bff) discusses the hows, whys, and sources of each of the four. So yes, a few very famous rabbis have written at least a section of a book about it. Off the top of my head I couldn't tell you what they said, though.